# Repetier-host icons mess

Tags: unity, icons, dock

When I start my application (Repetier Host) it create a weird icon in the dock ! How can I have only one Repetier icon in my dock ?

I like to have a clean looking dock and a nice empty desktop but with this weird icon in the dock, all my life is ruined.

Please help !

I already tried to : 
I have run `xprop WM_CLASS` and clicked the application window.
I should get some output like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"`**. 
I would like to add the class as the value of `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file. For example, `StartupWMClass=Firefox`

But it is not working ! Because I do not see an output like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"` I see this :

```
labprinter@labprinterPC:~$ xprop WM_CLASS

WM_CLASS:  not found.
```

I use Repetier-host V1.6.2, on Ubuntu 16.04,

[Open the screen capture !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LAT0.png)